Rails action mailer - How to embed images in a way that email clients like Gmail can display?
I am trying to send emails in my Ruby on Rails app via Rail's action mailer. I want to embed images as they are dynamically generated, and small in file size (It's a QR code). I do not want to host these files on my server. Given those requirements, inline images seemed to be the way to go. The documentation gives a basic example:
# In your mailer function
attachments.inline['image.jpg'] = File.read('/path/to/image.jpg')
# In your email template
<%= image_tag attachments['image.jpg'].url %>

This only works in certain email clients though. For example, this worked for outlook but not Gmail. In Gmail the image is added to the email as an attachment:

But it is not displayed:

I am fairly sure the issue isn't with the file itself as I can download the gmail attachment and view the QR code in any image preview app. Does anyone know the most compatible way to embed images into action mailer emails?
Other things I have tried that have worked in outlook but not Gmail
# I saw some people with this issue saying defining the content arg worked. Not for Gmail
attachments.inline['image.jpg'] = { content: myfile }
# I saw some people say setting the mime_type and or encoding worked. Not for Gmail
attachments.inline['qr_code'] = {
          :data => myfile,
          :mime_type => "image/png",
          :encoding => "base64"
        }

